# In processing 2 is it possible to name a shape rect() to then refer to later?

Tags: processing

Can you name a primitive shape such as rect() in some way, so you can then later change its properties ?

Or some other way to achieve my goal?

http://processing.org/reference/rect_.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PShape](http://processing.org/reference/PShape.html), and there is pretty good tutorial [here](http://processing.org/tutorials/pshape/). I created some simple demonstration how to use it:

```java
PShape rectangle;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P2D);
  rectangle = createShape(RECT, 0, 0, 100, 50);
  rectangle.setStroke(color(255));
  rectangle.setStrokeWeight(4);
  rectangle.setFill(color(127));
}

void draw() {
  background(51);
  translate(mouseX, mouseY);
  shape(rectangle);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == CODED) {
    if (keyCode == UP) {
      rectangle.scale(1.1);
    } 
    else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
      rectangle.scale(0.9);
    }
  }
}
```